# SWF Editor/Decompiler

Tags: flash, editor, swf

I am searching for a good, and preferably free, SWF editor and/or decompiler. 
I do not have access to the original FLAs.

Does anyone know of a program that would accomplish this?

Comment: Nope, not outside of Adobe's powerhouse, and that's expensive.

Comment: :S Why hasn't anyone reversed-engineered that proprietary format yet? It would seem that I'm not the only one who's looking for this..

Comment: Decompilers exist. Answer incoming after I check my notes :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can decompile, edit, and recompile SWF using swfmill. This tool turns a SWF into XML and back again, e.g.:

`swfmill swf2xml movie.swf movie.xml`

`swfmill xml2swf movie.xml movie.swf`

However, whether this will be useful to you depends on how the SWF is put together. You can edit images, videos, audio etc within the movie using this method. They are present in the XML file as base64 encoded blocks which you can replace.

Editing text is much harder because text in SWF files is usually converted to curves so that the fonts do not need to be embedded.

Comment: Thanks! That's actually really cool. I'm happily perusing through the SWF's exported XML now! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use "ffdec", a SWF decompiler and editor, a.k.a. JPEXS Free Flash Decompiler.

https://github.com/jindrapetrik/jpexs-decompiler/releases